# Can't get data from MySql with using php to Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-status-code-403

I have created an app, that fetchs data from mysql using php. But when i call the php file from my android app i got following out put in my LogCat window.

```
08-26 21:07:57.748: V/(1036): Response : org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f8b018
08-26 21:07:57.758: V/(1036): Entity : org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@44f8c730
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): Result : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): <html><head>
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): <title>403 Forbidden</title>
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): </head><body>
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): <h1>Forbidden</h1>
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): <p>You don't have permission to access /PHP/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): on this server.</p>
08-26 21:07:57.839: V/(1036): </body></html>
```

But when i run .php using wamp server then it can get data successfully. I can't understand where i have made the mistake.

Following is my android code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.167.122.24 /PHP/  getAllPeopleBornAfter.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    Log.v("","Response : "+response);
    Log.v("","Entity : "+entity);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
    Log.v("","Result : "+result);
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e);
}
```

Please give me some idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did your server have htaccess authentication ?

Comment: thank you for suggest me but can you please tell me where i can find htaccess authentication. i having use wamp server in my local machine. waiting for your replay.........

Comment: when you open this url in browser it will ask for credential if your server have htaccess authentication..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Here's the relevant message:

`You don't have permission to access /PHP/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php`

2) This is coming from your Windows server.

You HAVE permission to "reach out" the the internet from your Android phone.

3) You *haven't* given permission for remote clients (not just Android, but *any* web browser on any other PC on your network() access to the files.

SUGGESTION:

4) Check httpd.conf and/or .htaccess permissions for your web server root directory.

Here's a good link and a good example:

- http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,49649

  ```
      #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
      Allow from IP_ADDRESS_ABC
      ...
      Allow from IP_ADDRESS_XYZ
  </Directory>
  ```

Comment: thank you very much to replay me. But can you please tell me in brief where htaccess permission i can found in web server root directory. I having use wamp server.

Comment: @alex_android_dev - I would start with `<Directory>` in your http.conf file.  There are many links that explain it, including the one that I cited, and the WAMP documentation.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your error logs says that you have forgot to give Internet Permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

Just write following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Really? Surely that 403 is coming back from the server, not being generated within Android?

Comment: @therefromhere - you're absolutely correct.  This *is* an error 403 from the *server*.  Android is successfully connecting to the WAMP server.

Comment: ya and also i have already put that permission in my androidmanifest

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have internet permissions in your Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: ya i have already put that permission in my androidmanifest.xml

Comment: ahh I'm sorry :/ and also I didn't see that someone also posted that answer. I think we posted at the same time ><... I'll look at other options but @paulsm4 seems pretty plausible